# Base Class object array pointing to an instance of derived class syntax?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, pointers, inheritance

If I have a base class called Book and create an array of Book pointers, how can I dynamically create an instance of a NonFiction or Fiction (both derived classes) in my Book pointer? I added what I am trying to do but unsure how the correct syntax for doing something like this is.

```
   Book* v;
   v = new Book[10]
   v[2] = new Fiction
```

Comment: Well, what happens? Does it compile? If not, what are the error messages from your compiler, and show a complete [mre]? If it does compile, does it run and give correct results? If not, once again: show a complete [mre]. Try temporarily forget everything, and read your question as it would be read by a complete stranger, with no other knowledge at all; do you think you'll be able to understand what's being asked here?

Comment: Please note that you should not use `new` like this if you are not forced to. Instead use `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Book>>`. Using `new` like this only causes trouble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not creating an array of `Book` pointers, you are creating an array of 10 `Book` objects. To create an array of pointers, you want

```
Book **v = new Book*[10];
v[2] = new Fiction;
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstable, in c++, I recommand using smart pointers as much as possible. Also I like STL vectors.

In your case, I would do something like that :

```
       std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Book>> books(10, nullptr);
       books[2] = std::make_shared<Fiction>();
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any reason to use `std::shared_ptr` here. Prefer `std::unique_ptr` if you don't actually require shared ownership.

Comment: Minor terminology issue.  STL is _NOT_ what you want to use. You should prefer to use the C++ Standard Library, as it is already part of the most recent C++ compilers.  From wikipedia 'Standard Template Library':   "The Standard Template Library (STL) is a software library for the C++ programming language that influenced many parts of the C++ Standard Library."   I'm not sure if the STL is available or up-to-date (I once used Dinkum Library, which claimed it to be a conforming implementation of the Standard C++ library...").